# Print img source not img itself not work when img from localhost

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am try to print image when user click on it.

It work when the img from internet, but it does not work when it is from my own pc (localhost). But why?

I try many scripts but all give me the same result.

thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="tab"><img style="width:600px; hieght:600px;" src="https://scontent.fgza6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/90511757_144802246885621_238915900961456128_n.jpg?_nc_cat=111&_nc_sid=b96e70&_nc_ohc=r3aJA4RgmrIAX9uj7MO&_nc_ht=scontent.fgza6-1.fna&oh=bc1a6cdf63922303eb725277d019cffa&oe=5EA69107" alt="Bald Eagle" />
        </div> 


    <div id="tab2"><img style="width:600px; hieght:600px;" src="http://localhost:8000/storage/images/VW5wb8YGHetqZy8BKcnQuCVGcJwqXgakKViyeuoV.jpeg" alt="Bald Eagle" />
        </div>

    <p>
        <input type="button" value="Print img" onclick="myApp.print()" /> <!-- it's work -->
        <input type="button" value="Print img local" onclick="myApp2.printLocal()" /> <!-- it not work !! -->
    </p>
</body>
<script>
    var myApp = new function () {
        this.print = function () {
            var tab = document.getElementById('tab');
            var win = window.open('', '', 'height=508,width=580');
            win.document.write(tab.outerHTML);
            win.document.close();
            win.print();
        }
    }

    var myApp2 = new function () {
        this.printLocal = function () {
            var tab = document.getElementById('tab2');
            var win = window.open('', '', 'height=508,width=580');
            win.document.write(tab.outerHTML);
            win.document.close();
            win.print();
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: is the image on local host in a folder that the server can access?

Comment: yes, sure and i show it in img tag it is appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your code on localhost its working perfectly and i did gave the 
`src="/storage/images/VW5wb8YGHetqZy8BKcnQuCVGcJwqXgakKViyeuoV.jpeg"` instead of    `src="http://localhost:8000/storage/images/VW5wb8YGHetqZy8BKcnQuCVGcJwqXgakKViyeuoV.jpeg"`

Try your luck

To print from the file upload

HTML

```
<input type="file" accept="img/*" onchange="fileChanged(event)" />
```

JS

```
function fileChanged(e){
  let file=e.target.files[0];  document.querySelector('#tab2>img').src=window.URL.createObjectURL(file); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="tab"><img style="width:100px; height:100px;" src="https://scontent.fgza6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/90511757_144802246885621_238915900961456128_n.jpg?_nc_cat=111&_nc_sid=b96e70&_nc_ohc=r3aJA4RgmrIAX9uj7MO&_nc_ht=scontent.fgza6-1.fna&oh=bc1a6cdf63922303eb725277d019cffa&oe=5EA69107" alt="Bald Eagle" />
        </div> 


    <div id="tab2"><img style="width:100px; height:100px;" src="" />
        </div>

    <p>
        <input type="button" value="Print img" onclick="myApp.print()" /> <!-- it's work -->
        <input type="file" accept="img/*" onchange="fileChanged(event)" /> 
        <input type="button" value="Print img local" onclick="myApp2.printLocal()" /> <!-- it not work !! -->
    </p>
</body>
<script>
    var myApp = new function () {
        this.print = function () {
            var tab = document.querySelector('#tab>img');
            var win = window.open('', '', 'height=508,width=580');
            win.document.write(tab.outerHTML);
            win.document.close();
            win.print();
        }
    }
    function fileChanged(e){
      let file=e.target.files[0];  document.querySelector('#tab2>img').src=window.URL.createObjectURL(file); 
    }
    var myApp2 = new function () {
        this.printLocal = function () {
            var tab = document.querySelector('#tab2>img');
            var win = window.open('', '', 'height=508,width=580');
            win.document.write(tab.outerHTML);
            win.document.close();
            win.print();
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```